# How to move one folder back in java while importing packages

Tags: java

I have one Folder by the name of "java" which has two folders "Search","Demo".
in "Search" folder I have so many class including `"BinarySearch.java"` and in "Demo" folder I have class `"Demo.java"` I want to import "BinarySearch.java" class in the "Demo.java" class.
So I tried this:

- First in "BinarySearch.java" I put this line of code `package Search;`
- in "Demo.java" I put this line of code `import Search.BinarySearch.java`

But this solution only works only when I move the "Demo.java" file in "java" folder. but I need to import "BinarySearch.java" without moving my file into "java" folder.

See the error If don't move the file into "java" folder
[image]

So I need to move back one folder while importing.

Comment: Remove `.java`, and then read [the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

In Demo/Demo.java

```
package Demo;

import Search.BinarySearch;

public class Demo {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In Search/BinarySearch.java

```
package Search;

public class BinarySearch  {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It is always a good practice to use lower case for your package names. Example: `demo` or `search`.

Comment: I updated the question with a picture that's the error I encounter while Im doing your approach.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the folder structure of your Java files as well?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of Demo/Demo.java must be "package Demo".
The same as the first line of Search/BinarySearch.java is "package Search".